# Intellij IDEA 2:2016.2.4-1 : Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_111-b01: Java 1.8 or later is required

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently downloaded Intellij IDEA, and am trying to run it. But when I try to open the program (either through Gnome's menu, or idea.sh), it crashes with the message "Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_111-b01: Java 1.8 or later is required.".

I have tried setting the `IDEA_JDK_64` and `IDEA_JDK` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre`, but that doesn't help.

I'm using Arch Linux, with the Community edition of IDEA downloaded from community.

Comment: Do you have Java 7 installed anywhere on your system at all?

Comment: Have you Java 1,7 installed on your system. If yes it may be worth a try to deinstall it if you don't need it.

Comment: So removed all the JDK7 stuff, and set JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk" in /etc/environment. Now I can start Intellij by running idea.sh, but not via the gnome menu.

Comment: I restarted and it worked, thanks. If Makoto makes a answer, I will accept.

Comment: You can also make an answer for yourself here; don't be shy about that.  My comment was only meant to clarify whether or not you had Java 7 installed anywhere in your PATH.

Comment: @Jones Please write and accept an answer as Makoto suggested, these comments helped me but someone less patient may hit that back button when they see there's no answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled JDK7, and set my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk"`.

This fixed the problem.